# Live Video Streaming from Webcam to Website

Tags: real-time, webcam, live-streaming

Trying to figure out the best way to allow users to enable their webcams to stream live to my server so others can view the streams.

I've read a handful of posts on here but haven't seen a good example of a solution for this.

Really just looking for what needs to be done to have their webcam turn on and stream the feed to my server and what needs to be done to push that feed out to a page viewable by others.

I believe Adobe Flash Player would be the best to receive the feed and display for others but again need some guidance here on how to put this all together.

Any direction is much appreciated!

Thanks,

NCoder

Comment: I've heard stuff about Red5 and Flash Media Server as well.  Not sure if either is required in this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will require Javascript + Adobe Flash Player, the user will grant permission for their cam to be accessed.

For Adobe:
http://www.adobe.com

For Javascript:
    
    $int event
    startcam-on.user 
    open.? Rec.begin (int)

Comment: Thanks for the note, this is a good start.  Can you provide some more detail on how the video is pushed to my server and how it's displayed on a page?

Comment: It looks like I could use something like this to boot up the camera, but how about pushing it to my server and displaying on a page viewable for others? http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

Comment: Check these out: 1.http://bit.ly/XltLuQ 2.http://bit.ly/c8LYyY 3.http://bit.ly/Qppc7